# Android brightness change notification (or status bar roll-up notification)

Tags: android

In Android user can change brightness by "rolling down" the status bar (or notification bar, whatever this is called in Android) and changing brightness there.

I need to display brightness slider in my app. I know how to get system brightness value, but the question is how to know if user changed the brightness? When user rolls-up the notification bar I don't get onResume. How do I know that the brightness has changed or the notification bar revealed my activity to the user?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46119279/how-to-detect-if-screen-brightness-has-changed-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating a thread with a runnable that runs indefinitely (or till you want it to run) where you listen for a change in the current brightness. This can be done pretty easily

1. Find the original screen brightness and assign it to a variable called oldScreenBrightness.
2. In your thread check

   ```
   currentScreenBrightness = getCurrentScreenBrightness();
   if (oldScreenBrightness != currentScreenBrightness)
   {
       doSomething()
       oldScreenBrightness = currentScreenBrightness
   }
   else
   {
      doNothing or doSomethingElse
   }
   ```

Comment: my god, is it the only way? when posting my question i was about to write "and please don't tell me i have to resort to polling" :) android is ridiculous :(

Comment: I've looked into this issue in the past and after much research I came to the conclusion that this was the only solution. Android is actually pretty amazing but yours in a an extremely niche case I'd say.

Comment: after two years of programming for iPhone and one year Android I have my own opinion about the latter ;) thanks for the answer, I'll accept it after a few days if nobody comes up with some more event-based solution.

Comment: haha very well then, I think I should try out iPhone dev, now only if Objective-C didn't look so messy.

Comment: yes, I interned there over the last two months. I'm sorry but who are you?

Comment: Yes, I've just finished my 1st year of Bachelor of Engineering and Computer Science.

Answer (score -1):

Go to settings 
Select display 
Select notification panel
Check 
Brightness adjustment

Comment: that's not programing way,just change the setting.