# How to detect if screen brightness has changed in Android?

Tags: android, screen-brightness

I have searched extensively and couldn't find a similar question.

I would like to know if there is any way to detect when the screen brightness of a mobile device has been changed.

I have already tried to store the old value when the app starts and repeatedly check using`Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);` to compare the initial and final value of screen brightness , which is not a good way of doing so.

Thanks

EDIT: This question states that I have already tried the solution of using `Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS` to get current screen values and periodically check for screen brightness changes. I am looking for a more efficient way of doing such an operation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get preferred screen brightness in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544967/get-preferred-screen-brightness-in-android)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any system level broadcast about the screen brightness so you cannot know when the user changed it unless you keep polling, which I agree is not the best practice. Add to it the issue that @Michael just linked and you got a pretty hard problem in your hands.

Comment: @Michael the problem being discussed there suggests the same method I have already tried, I was looking for an alternative solution :D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

yes, there is a way by using [ContentObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html):

- code:

  ```
    // listen to the brightness system settings
    val contentObserver = object:ContentObserver(Handler())
    {
        override fun onChange(selfChange:Boolean)
        {
            // get system brightness level
            val brightnessAmount = Settings.System.getInt(
                    contentResolver,Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS,0)

            // do something...
        }
    }

    // register the brightness listener upon starting
    contentResolver.registerContentObserver(
            Settings.System.getUriFor(Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS),
            false,contentObserver)

    // .....

    // unregister the listener when we're done (e.g. activity destroyed)
    contentResolver.unregisterContentObserver(contentObserver)
  ```

other useful links:

- [what thread is ContentObserver.onChange called on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21380914/contentobserver-onchange)
- [Change the System Brightness Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312609/change-the-system-brightness-programmatically)

Comment: Thank you for your method, but permission is not required, because we get the system settings, not set them

Answer (score 5):

There are no receivers provided to detect brightness change.

You have to run a **Service** or **Thread** to check the brightness change by yourself.

```
Settings.System.getInt(getContext().getContentResolver(), 
             Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
```

The above code will give you current system brightness level. Periodically detect the brightness and compare with the old one.

Note: If the system is in Auto Brightness mode, you can't get current brightness level. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8114307/5558150).

Comment: I have already tried out this method (already stated in question) , was looking for a more efficient way to do so.

Comment: The answer is no. There is no method to do it efficiently. See the link I have shared in the answer.